# creating class function macro

Tags: c++, winapi

I wanted to know if there was a easier way to create virtual functions in my class, and then a macro to call them.

```
        virtual int Controller::OnClose(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, bool& bHandled) { return 0; }
        virtual int Controller::OnDestroy(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, bool& bHandled) { return 0; }
        virtual int Controller::OnPaint(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, bool& bHandled) { return 0; }

        case WM_CREATE:         lRes = OnCreate(wParam, lParam, bHandled);      break;
        case WM_DESTROY:        lRes = OnDestroy(wParam, lParam, bHandled);     break;
        case WM_PAINT:          lRes = OnPaint(wParam, lParam, bHandled);       break;
```

Comment: Use a lookup table instead of `switch/case`.

Comment: Simply write out the code in your base class, and rely on virtual dispatch to let derived classes customize the behavior. A macro isn't going to be of much help. It'll make the code harder to read and debug, with very little to be gained. Incidentally, what are you trying to gain from using a macro here?

Comment: i wanted to use a macro to shorten the code and less typing, thought it would look neater since every function im passing the same arguments.

Comment: If you already are going to go through the hassle of dispatching messages to member functions, why aren't you doing it properly, by passing properly typed arguments? E.g. [WM_CREATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632619.aspx) receives a `CREATESTRUCT` through its `lParam`. The other 2 messages don't have any additional information attached. But anyway, using macros here will simply make it **very** hard to debug the code.

Comment: I tend to agree with @IInspectable here. Debugging through those macros will take years off your life. If you absolutely must, ATL already solved this problem with [message map macros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hk23896b.aspx).

Comment: i wont need to debug the virtual functions, just the function in the other class

Comment: This looks to be library code you plan to deploy to others. Users of your library may want to have a means to easily debug through your library code. I know, I wish MFC weren't such a chore to debug, due to abundant use of preprocessor macros. Regardless, if you find your macros so trivial that they do not need debugging, then likely, they are not worth it to begin with. As I said, at the very least you'd want to filter and properly convert the types prior to passing them to your member functions. If you need inspiration, have a look at the *"message crackers"* in *Windowsx.h*.